# Get path of file from File object js

Tags: javascript, browser

I want to get path of a file picked from dialog of browser or for more specific, from File object. And, I try inspecting it, then I cant got its path:
[image]

But, when I read File object schema then I don't see path property described at here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File
So, does it have anything confused at here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get full path of selected file on change of <input type=‘file’> using javascript, jquery-ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav)

Comment: You may want to look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL